# Facebook login not working after LoginManager's logOut

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing a Facebook login with the SDK 4 but it only works once.

When I install the app I can login with Facebook perfectly. However, when I logout and try to login again, I get the **Sorry, something went wrong** message:

[image: Sorry, something went wrong message]

How I init SDK:

```
// Called in onCreate()
private void initFacebook() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "On success");
                    getUserData(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (callbackManager != null) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void getUserData(AccessToken accessToken) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            accessToken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject json,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.v(TAG, response.toString());
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // handle error
                        Log.d(TAG, "GraphRequest error");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "GraphRequest success");
                        try {

                            String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                            Log.d(TAG, "JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                            String str_email = json.getString("email");
                            String str_id = json.getString("id");
                            String str_name = json.getString("name");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        onLoginSuccess();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

And here the login and logout:

```
@Override
public void onLoginClicked() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
}

@Override
public void onLogoutClicked() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

What is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first of all initialize facebook sdk , just before `setContentview();`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

then in `onResume()` you should call

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
```

in `onPause()` call following:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //for facebook
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }
```

except this your code is looking fine, yesterday i also got some problem like this, i guess it is problem from Facebook, because today my app work fine automatically.